# Remove all symbols except "no_mangle extern" ones in Rust's `staticlib`? (since it is to be used by C program and all other symbols are useless)

Tags: rust, linker, compiler-construction

I am building a static lib (`.a`) from some Rust code, and this `.a` file will be used (linked) by an iOS app. However, that `.a` file contains tons of symbols - Rust functions that are only to be used *internally* instead of exposing to the iOS app. Indeed, the Rust code uses `#[no_mangle] pub extern "C" fn` to expose the apis that will be used by the iOS app. All other functions will never be used and should not appear in the final app.

Therefore, I wonder how can I remove all symbols except "no_mangle extern" ones in Rust's `staticlib`?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You should just not mark them as public, then it won't export symbols

Comment: @AlexandreSenges However I do need to write integration tests on them...

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, you can use a conditional compilation macro to only build integration tests for tests

Comment: @AlexandreSenges Sounds reasonable. Thanks!